# Material ui is not applying custom changes on elements in next js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am using `material UI` in `NEXTJS` and on first render sometimes its applying all the custom changes sometimes it doesn't. when it applying all those and click on link its breaking again and I did all the custom changes which mentioned https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs here like creating custom `_app.js` and `_document.js` file

`_app.js`

```
import { useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from '../src/theme';
import "../styles/globals.css";


export default function  MyApp({ Component, pageProps }){

    useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    console.log(jssStyles);
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

    return (<>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>)
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

`_document.js`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import theme from '../src/theme';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with static-site generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();


  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => <App {...props} />,
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
  };
};
```

any help would appreciated